# what is the equivalent of _emit in MASM

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, inline-assembly, masm

I'm trying to port some inline assembly code written in Visual Studio into MASM64. The original code uses _emit which is a pseudo instruction that defines one byte at the current location in the current text segment.

How would I do the same in x64 assembly MASM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `db`, as in:

```
db 10h
```

You do this most often in a data segment, unless things have changed in the 64-bit version of MASM, it should work in the code segment as well.