# In C programming, what does "emit" do?

Tags: c, byte, emit

I recently tried to expand my knowledge of the C language and I came across a program that used emit, to possibly *emit* a byte.

```
__declspec(naked) void marker_begin() {
__asm {
    _emit 0x51;
    _emit 0x21;
    _emit 0x1A;
    _emit 0x14;
    _emit 0x2C;
    _emit 0x5B;
}
```

}

What could this be used for?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks like inline assembler to me.

Comment: @Musa Thanks, you're definitely right. What does "emit" do in an inline assembler?

Comment: db is the similar instruction, see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916050/what-is-the-equivalent-of-emit-in-masm

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/1b80826t(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your C program is executing inline assembly code by using the `_asm` keyword. _asm is a Microsoft specific keyword used in `MSDN`. The `__asm` keyword invokes the inline assembler. It must be followed by an assembly instruction, a group of instructions enclosed in braces, or, at least, an empty pair of braces.

The `_emit` pseudo instruction is similar to the `DB` directive of `MASM`. `_emit` is an `MSDN` specific pseudo instruction. `_emit` is used to define a single immediate byte at the current location in the current text segment. `_emit` can define only one byte at a time and only in the text segment.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would upvote you but I don't have the reputation.